# Knockout drag and drop : On drag enter hiding div and on drag leave show div [Mine is different]

Tags: jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I am new to knockout JavaScript. in my project I am using Knockout drag and drop functionality. by initially i have two divisions one is visible and another one have property display none. when I am doing drag enter function I need to hide first division and show second division. once drag leave hide 2nd division and showing first division. But problem is when I was drag enter the second division functionality is changing I don't want to hide second division until drop. Please help me to resolve.

I don't want to change any html in ".typeTextareaSection"(which is having in code) block.

here is my fiddle [**Knockout Drag and drop Fiiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/kd7umbj4/)

[image]

```js
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    this.dropZones = ko.observableArray([{
        'elements' : ko.observableArray([])  // just to see that the output is correct
    }]);

   
    this.dragoverTextarea = function(e){
        console.log('dragOver');
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    this.dropTextarea = function(e, data){
        console.log('drop');
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            data.elements.push(f.name);
        }
        $('.typeTextarea').children('.typeTextareaSection').css('display', 'block');
   $('.typeTextarea').children('#dragtimeTextarea').css('display', 'none');

    }

    this.dragenterTextarea = function(e, index){
        console.log('dragEnter');
              $('.typeTextarea').eq(index).children('.typeTextareaSection').css('display', 'none');
   $('.typeTextarea').children('#dragtimeTextarea').css('display', 'block');
    }

    this.dragleaveTextarea = function(e, index){
        console.log('end');        
        $('.typeTextarea').children('.typeTextareaSection').css('display', 'block');
   $('.typeTextarea').children('#dragtimeTextarea').css('display', 'none');
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: dropZones">
    <div class="typeTextarea" style="margin-top: 20px; height: 120px; border: 2px dashed #bbb; padding: 10px;" data-bind="event: {
        dragover: function (data, e) { $root.dragoverTextarea(e); },
        drop: function (data, e) { $root.dropTextarea(e, $data); },
        dragenter: function (data, e) { $root.dragenterTextarea(e, $index()); },
        dragleave: function (data, e) { $root.dragleaveTextarea(e, $index()); }
    }">
  <div class="typeTextareaSection">
   <div class="headerForTypeArea">
    
             <img style="text-align: right; float: right; cursor: pointer;" src="Content/images/cancel27.png" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" />
    <img style="text-align: right; float: right; cursor: pointer;padding-right:5px;" src="Content/images/correctBox2.png" alt="Save" title="Save" />
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="ContentEditableSection">
                <textarea  class="ediitableTestAreaPlaceHolders" maxlength="25000" style="margin-bottom: 0px; height: 70px; width: 99%;" placeholder="drop files here..." ></textarea>

   </div>
  </div>

  <textarea id="dragtimeTextarea" placeholder="Over this area to check my problem" style="display:none;font-size:20px;color:#000;"></textarea>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of possible help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791721/implementing-html5-drag-and-drop-photos-with-knockout-js-durandal-2-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach to this problem is not structured enough.

The most important thing to internalize is that **every time you modify the DOM from within your viewmodel you are doing something wrong**. Your viewmodel must not know anything about your page structure, elements, CSS classes or DOM events. Your view is supposed to depend on your viewmodel, not the other way around.

The only place to do DOM interaction is: In a binding. If there is no built-in binding that does what you need then you can [create a custom one](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

In your case you want to encapsulate the operation of dropping files onto an element. This should have two effects:

- some elements should react visibly when you hover something
- the dropped files should go into an observable array

This effectively determines the interface of your binding:

- an observable that will store `true` when hovering and `false` otherwise
- an observable that will receive the dropped files

So let's call the new binding `filedrop`, and that's how it's going to be used:

```html
<div data-bind="filedrop: {hover: hovering, drop: files}"></div>
```

where `hovering` and `files` are observables in your viewmodel. Here's how the binding could look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.filedrop = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor();

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dragenter", function (e) {
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(options.hover)) options.hover(true);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dragleave", function (e) {
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(options.hover)) options.hover(false);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dragover", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "drop", function (e) {
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(options.drop)) {
                if (typeof options.drop.push === "function") {
                    options.drop.push.apply(options.drop, e.dataTransfer.files);
                } else {
                    options.drop(e.dataTransfer.files);
                }
            }
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(options.hover)) options.hover(false);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
};
```

Now you can clean up your viewmodel graph by creating a dedicated `DropZone` viewmodel that contains the `hovering` and `files` observables and other associated things:

```
function DropZone() {
    var self = this;
    self.text = ko.observable();
    self.files = ko.observableArray();
    self.hovering = ko.observable(false);
    self.filenames = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.files(), function (element) {
            return element.name;
        });
    });
}
```

Now your main view model is what it should be: A list of dropzones.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.dropZones = ko.observableArray([
        new DropZone()
    ]);
}
```

After that building the view is no problem anymore, either.

```html
<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: dropZones">
    <div class="dropZone" data-bind="filedrop: { hover: hovering, drop: files }">
        <div class="textPane" data-bind="visible: !hovering()">
            <div class="buttonBar">
                <img src="Content/images/cancel27.png" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" />
                <img src="Content/images/correctBox2.png" alt="Save" title="Save" />
            </div>
            <textarea maxlength="25000" data-bind="value: text" placeholder="Start typing here&hellip;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="dropPane" data-bind="visible: hovering">Drop files here&hellip;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All of this leaves you with

- a custom binding that you can re-use in a different place or project
- a set of viewmodels that actually contain only what they *should* contain
- an overall clean and maintainable setup

http://jsfiddle.net/kd7umbj4/2/

Comment: This solution is super thanks . But I need to change my implementation.